# iBeacon - how to detect a time a user spends in a room or department?

Tags: position, distance, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I have an app that monitors or ranges iBeacons inside a building. **How can I detect how long a user spends in a particular room?**

I've observed that the proximity for a given beacon may jump from near to far, based on orientation of the device. This means that I cannot simply say that once the range is unknown, the visit is over. Should I continuously range a distance to a beacon and consider the visit to start/end once I detect X consecutive "near/unknown" states for a given beacon?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee you will get any number of ranging callbacks with proximity "unknown" before a beacon disappears.  Instead, you should use the monitoring APIs, and consider a room exited when you get a call to `didExitRegion`.  Sometimes iOS will give you a spurious exit notification, so you need to protect against this.  I do so by starting a timer on region exit, and I only perform the exit logic if I don't get a `didEnterRegion` callback within five seconds.

Of course, all this assumes that the "room" or "department" has beacons whose transmitter range end precisely at the edge of the room/department.  Without very precise placement and control over transmitter power, this is unlikely to be exactly true.  You have to decide if you can live with this approximation.

Comment: I'm not sure if region monitoring would work for rooms with overlapping beacon signals -It's like one large region, and no guarantee that the user ever exits it.  To distinguish beacons in such case, I would have to create distinct UUIDs for beacons, and register to listen for a dozen different regions.

Comment: @AlexStone, totally agree that different regions would be needed for each room/department.